# Scrapy Middleware confusion

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

I am using the following code to incorporate proxies within my crawler: [Scrapy-Proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies/blob/master/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py)

With this code for my downloader middleware as per [setup instructions](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies/blob/master/README.md):

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}
```

All works fine, but I have now setup a new function within my spider class which updates the text file in which the proxies are kept (referenced by above source) with newer replacements.

I am looking for some general advice on what changes I would need to make to the middleware and/or source to get this code to 're-read' the text file on every request please? Thanks